# Change number format of a cell which inlude currecny using visual basic

Tags: excel, vb6

I want to add currency values with its type to a excel sheet. I have created the following code piece for that.

```
Public Sub WorkSheetForCurrencies(ByRef ProductsCollection As VBA.Collection, ByRef cur As String, ByRef ExgRate As Double, ByRef symbol As String)

Dim index As Long
Dim objProduct As Product

index = 2
For Each objProduct In ProductsCollection

    If symbol = "£" Then
    'Way 01:
        mobjCSVWorkSheet.Cells(index, 8).NumberFormat = "-[$£-809]* #,##0.00_-;-[$£-809]* #,##0.00_-;_-[$£-809]* " - "??_-;_-@_-"
    ElseIf symbol = "$" Then
    'Way 02:
        mobjCSVWorkSheet.Cells(index, 8).Select
        Selection.NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* " - "??_);_(@_)"
    ElseIf symbol = "€" Then
        mobjCSVWorkSheet.Cells(index, 8).NumberFormat = "_([$€-2] * #,##0.00_);_([$€-2] * (#,##0.00);_([$€-2] * " - "??_);_(@_)"
    End If

    mobjCSVWorkSheet.Cells(index, 8) = objProduct.SalesUnitPrice * CCur(ExgRate)
    index = index + 1
Next objProduct
End Sub
```

I have tried two ways to change the number format as in the above code. but those give **Type mismatch error** . Please tell me what I have to change in order to change the cell number format. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
"-[$£-809]* #,##0.00_-;-[$£-809]* #,##0.00_-;_-[$£-809]* " - "??_-;_-@_-"
```

This evaluates to

```
"-[$£-809]* #,##0.00_-;-[$£-809]* #,##0.00_-;_-[$£-809]* "
```

minus

```
"??_-;_-@_-"
```

Since you are performing an arithmetic operation on a string, it tries to convert both sides to a numeric value, and fails.

Try doubling up the double quotes, e.g.

```
"-[$£-809]* #,##0.00_-;-[$£-809]* #,##0.00_-;_-[$£-809]* "" - ""??_-;_-@_-"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It solved that type mismatch error. I got another issue, I saved the excel sheet in .csv format and when I look on the added cells with numbers as currency (as per the previous code), when I click on those cells in the excel sheet , they are just 'Normal' type cells, not currency  type. What I need to do to change that?

Comment: Saving as CSV only saves the data. You'l have to manually reformat each column.